# Why are my threads suddenly stopping in Java?

Tags: java, concurrency

I am supposed to be using two custom Semaphore classes (binary and counting) to print off letters in an exact sequence. Here is the standard semaphore.

```
public class Semaphore {

protected int value;

public Semaphore() {
    value = 0;
}

public Semaphore(int initial) {
    value = (initial >=0) ? initial : 0;
}

public synchronized void P() throws InterruptedException {
    while (value==0) {
        wait();
    }
    value--;
}

public synchronized void V() {
    value++;
    notify();
}
}
```

And here is the binary semaphore:

```
public class BinarySemaphore extends Semaphore {

public BinarySemaphore(boolean unlocked) {super(unlocked ? 1 : 0);}

public synchronized void P() throws InterruptedException{
    while(value==0) {
        wait();
    }
    value=0;
}

public synchronized void V() {
    value=1;
    notify();
}
}
```

Here is the main bulk of the code, except for a reason I can't work out why the threads stop after around thirty or so repetitions. Wait isn't called, the criteria for being true are being reached, so why aren't they working? Any help is much appreciated.

```
        BinarySemaphore binaryWXSemaphore = new BinarySemaphore(false);
        BinarySemaphore binaryYZSemaphore = new BinarySemaphore(false);

        Semaphore countingWSemaphore = new Semaphore();
        Semaphore countingYZSemaphore = new Semaphore();

        Runnable runnableW = () -> {
            while(true) {
                if (binaryWXSemaphore.value == 0 && countingYZSemaphore.value >= countingWSemaphore.value) {
                        binaryWXSemaphore.V();
                        countingWSemaphore.V();
                    System.out.println("W");
                }
            }
        };

        Runnable runnableX = () -> {
            while(true) {
                if (binaryWXSemaphore.value == 1) {
                    try {
                        binaryWXSemaphore.P();
                        System.out.println("X");

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        Runnable runnableY = () -> {
            while(true) {
                if (binaryYZSemaphore.value == 0 && countingWSemaphore.value > countingYZSemaphore.value) {
                        binaryYZSemaphore.V();
                        countingYZSemaphore.V();
                    System.out.println("y");

                }

            }
        };

        Runnable runnableZ = () -> {
            while(true) {
                if (binaryYZSemaphore.value == 1 && countingWSemaphore.value > countingYZSemaphore.value) {
                    try {
                        binaryYZSemaphore.P();
                        countingYZSemaphore.V();
                        System.out.println("z");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: Semaphores are invented not for direct accessing their `.value` field. Most likely your task should be implemented in a different way.

Comment: Indeed -- reading the .value field outside the monitor is unsynchronized access, and is therefore liable to race conditons.  The value should be private and only examined in synchronized methods.

Comment: There's also a Java-specific problem in that (for example) runnableW has no guarantee it will ever see the current value of either of the .value fields, because it never synchronizes on them.   'Synchronized' is not just about concurrency of modifications, it affects visibility as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @iggy points out the issue is related to fact that different threads are reading different values of `value`, because the way you access it isn't thread safe. Some threads may be using an old copy of the value. Making it volatile will mean each thread access reads more consistent value:

```
protected volatile int value;
```

Or switch to `AtomicInteger` which ensures thread consistent change to the int stored in `value`. You'll also need to replace the assignments using set/get/inc/decrement methods of `AtomicInteger`:

```
protected final  AtomicInteger value = new AtomicInteger();
// Then use value.set(0 / 1)
// or value.incrementAndGet / decrementAndGet
```

Unfortunately, even with the above changes, you may find other issues because `value` could change in the duration between each Runnable's if statement, and the operations inside those `if` branches.

Also: replacing `notify()` by `notifyAll()` usually gives better multi-thread handling though I don't think this necessarily helps in your example.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I thought that you have changed specifier to `protected`, but it actually was so in the question post itself. Still, external access to the `.value` field of the semaphore is bad because it is against the semaphore nature. Even if there is no race conditions.